# Asynchronous redirect StandardOutput and StandardError

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, cmd

I'm trying to redirect the stdout and stderr of a long process. It's an Exe that could take 40 minutes until it finished processing.

The issue is that if I run the EXE from command-line (cmd), stdout and stderr are displayed on console in a certain order,
and that's the order I'd like it to be redirected from my application, but it does not work. The order is changed when I use the following function, and can't find out what the reason is. I'd appreciate an advice.

This is the code I use:

```
Public numOutputLines As Integer = 0
Public sortOutput As StringBuilder = Nothing


Public Function ProcessTask3New(ByVal ExeName As String, ByVal arguments As String, ByRef stdout As String, ByRef stderr As String, ByRef ExitCode As Integer, _
                                  Optional ByVal Filename As String = "", Optional ByVal IsDeleteTempLogFiles As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        ' This fucntion executes cmd commands and arguments,
        ' Function returns standard output and startdard error. stderr contains data if error was generated 


        Try
            ProcessTask3New = True

            Dim p As Process
            Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo


            Dim currentTime As System.DateTime
            currentTime = System.DateTime.Now

            If Filename <> "" Then Filename = Replace(Filename & ".", "\", "")

            Dim tmpStdoutFilename As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "stdout." & Filename & currentTime.Ticks.ToString()
            Dim tmpStderrFilename As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath & "stderr." & Filename & currentTime.Ticks.ToString()


            netOutput = New StringBuilder
            p = New Process
            psi = p.StartInfo

            psi.Arguments = psi.Arguments.Replace("/C " & Chr(34), "/C " & Chr(34) & Chr(34))

            psi.FileName = ExeName
            psi.UseShellExecute = False
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized

            ' Redirect the standard output of the sort command.   
            ' Read the stream asynchronously using an event handler.
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            psi.RedirectStandardError = True
            psi.CreateNoWindow = True
            sortOutput = New StringBuilder()

            ' Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output. 
            AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, _
                       AddressOf SortOutputHandler


            AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf SortOutputHandler





            If IsDebug Then Write2Log("ProcessTask3New: " + psi.FileName.ToString + " " + psi.Arguments.ToString)

            Try
                Write2Log(My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory)

                p.Start()
            Catch w As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
                Write2Log("ProcessTask3New: " & w.Message)
                Write2Log("ProcessTask3New: " & w.ErrorCode.ToString())
                Write2Log("ProcessTask3New: " & w.NativeErrorCode.ToString())
                Write2Log("ProcessTask3New: " & w.StackTrace)
                Write2Log("ProcessTask3New: " & w.Source)

                Dim e As New Exception()
                e = w.GetBaseException()
                Write2Log("ProcessTask3New: " & e.Message)
            End Try




            ' Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
            p.BeginOutputReadLine()
            p.BeginErrorReadLine()

            p.WaitForExit()
            ExitCode = p.ExitCode

            p.Close()



            netOutput = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception
            Write2Log("error at ProcessTask3New function: " & ex.ToString & " : " + ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Sub SortOutputHandler(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, _
       ByVal outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)

        ' Collect the sort command output. 
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
            numOutputLines += 1

             Add the text to the collected output.
            sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + "[" _
                         + numOutputLines.ToString() + "] - " _
                         + outLine.Data)

        End If

    End Sub
```

**Now the output.**
This is how it looks when I run it from cmd window (this is GOOD):

> ---
>
> Processing key file: vob_db.k01(1), total of 291 nodes
>
> Processing delete chain:  1 node on delete chain. Processing nodes:
>   +++++++++10%+++++++++20%+++++++++30%+++++++++40%+++++++++50%+++++++++60%+++++++++70%+++++++++80%+++++++++90%+++++++++100 %
>
> ---
>
> Processing key file: vob_db.k02(2), total of 1246 nodes
>
> Processing delete chain:  2 nodes on delete chain. Processing nodes:
>   +++++++++10%+++++++++20%+++++++++30%+++++++++40%+++++++++50%+++++++++60%+++++++++70%+++++++++80%+++++++++90%+++++++++100 %
>
> ---
>
> Processing key file: vob_db.k03(5), total of 1 node
>
> Processing delete chain:  0 nodes on delete chain. Processing nodes:
>   100%
>
> ---
>
> Processing key file: vob_db.k04(6), total of 277 nodes
>
> Processing delete chain:  7 nodes on delete chain. Processing nodes:
>   +++++++++10%+++++++++20%+++++++++30%+++++++++40%+++++++++50%+++++++++60%+++++++++70%+++++++++80%+++++++++90%+++++++++100 %
>
> ---

(the lines like this one come from stderr.)

> +++++++++10%+++++++++20%+++++++++30%+++++++++40%+++++++++50%+++++++++60%++

This is how it looks when I run it from my application (this is BAD):

> ProcessTask3New: cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files
>   (x86).." -a -k -R -r1
>   -p29000 vob_db" E:\backup2\db db_VISTA Version 3.20 Database Consistency Check Utility Copyright (C) 1985-1990 Raima
>   Corporation, All Rights Reserved
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing key file: vob_db.k01(1), total of 291 nodes 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing key file: vob_db.k02(2), total of 1246 nodes
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing key file: vob_db.k03(5), total of 1 node
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing key file: vob_db.k04(6), total of 277 nodes
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing data file: vob_db.d01(0), total of 7107 records
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing data file: vob_db.d02(3), total of 20516 records 
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing data file: vob_db.d03(4), total of 1 record
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing data file: vob_db.d04(7), total of 0 records
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Processing data file: vob_db.d05(8), total of 39938 records Processing
>   delete chain:  1 node on delete chain. 0 errors were encountered in 0
>   records/nodes
>   +++++++++10%+++++++++20%+++++++++30%+++++++++40%+++++++++50%+++++++++60%+++++++++70%+++++++++80%+++++++++90%+++++++++100% Processing delete chain:  2 nodes on delete chain. Processing nodes:
>   +++++++++10%+++++++++20%+++++++++30%+++++++++40%+++++++++50%+++++++++60%+++++++++70%+++++++++80%+++++++++90%+++++++++100%  Processing delete chain:  0 nodes on delete chain. Processing nodes:
>   100%

Please advice. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind different orders is that when in console, a single output stream is indeed assigned to both "standard output" and "error output", and when called by your application, there are two streams that are not synchronized, thus your `SortOutputHandler` events are called in any order (if there were extremely long pauses between writes to the outputs or flushes it could get ordered correctly by chance).

The only solution you have to get this well sorted is to ensure that there is a single stream. The problem is that I am not aware of a solution allowing this using the ProcessStartInfo class.
One possibility would be to start the process in "pause" mode, then redirect forcefully its standard error handle to the output handle, then let it run (as `cmd.exe` does)

Answer (score 2):

You have the option to "mix" the stdout and stderr, redirecting the stderr into stdout

```
cmd /c "commandToRun 2>&1"
```

Here we are asking `cmd` to execute some command and redirect the stream 2 (stderr) sending its output to stream 1 (stdout).

BUT, obviously you will not retrieve any data on stderr.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it before posting here (and it didn't retrieve data on stderr as you said)